# ObjectInputStream readObject returning null only on some android devices

Tags: java, android, libgdx, serializable

I'm working on a game that uses `libgdx`, I save the game's state by saving a class that implements `Serializable`. It works fine on desktop and a couple of android devices I own but it is still crushing on other people's devices. I have to no idea what's causing it.

Here is how I save and load the object:

```
public static GameData gd;

final static String fileName = "sa.sav";

public static void save() {
    try {

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                Gdx.files.local(fileName).write(false));

        out.writeObject(gd);
        out.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }
}

public static void load() {
    try {
        if(!saveFileExists()) {
            init();
            return;
        }

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                Gdx.files.local(fileName).read());

        Gdx.app.log("Save", "in = " + in);
        gd = (GameData) in.readObject();
        Gdx.app.log("Save", "gd = " + gd);
        in.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }
}

public static boolean saveFileExists() {
    return Gdx.files.local(fileName).exists();
}

public static void init() {
    gd = new GameData();
    gd.init();
    save();
}
```

**The GameData Class:**

```
public class GameData implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

private int highScores;
private int totalCoins;
final int currentCharacterListVersion = 2;
private int userCharacterListVersion;

private boolean soundEnabled = true;
private float sfxVolume = 6f;
private float musicVolume = 6f;
private int lastLoginDay = 330;
private int dailyBonusCount = 0;

ArrayList<String> characters;

MyMap charList = new MyMap();
MyMap locationList = new MyMap();
```

}

Where `MyMap` contains 2 Maps and a few functions.

I'm not really familiar on how to deal with `Serializable objects` hence I don't know what to do. I can't use `Libgdx Preferences`, I'm not only storing `Strings` and `Integers` but also `Maps`. So any help as to why it's working on some devices only.

Comment: It is unclear where and which errror you have.

Comment: @blackapps variables in the GameData Class return null

Comment: A variable cannot return anything. Only a function.

Comment: @blackapps I mean there is nothing stored in the variable

Comment: Which variable? You gave not a single problem description. Reread your post!

Comment: @blackapps All of them